# uninitialized constant Specinfra::Command::Linuxmint error with Itamae

Tags: ruby, provisioning, itamae

I just installed LinuxMint17 Cinanmon in windows virtualbox environment and install ruby and itamae by:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
sudo gem i itamae
```

Then create a `recipe.rb`:

```
package 'git'
```

and run it by `sudo itamae local recipe.rb`, then I got error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/specinfra-2.44.7/lib/specinfra/command_factory.rb:31:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Specinfra::Command::Linuxmint (NameError)
```

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Specinfra` doesn't know about `linuxmint`, so we must create class for it in `recipe.rb`.

```
Specinfra::Command::Linuxmint = Class.new
Specinfra::Command::Linuxmint::Base = Class.new(Specinfra::Command::Ubuntu::Base)
Specinfra::Command::Linuxmint::Base::Ppa = Class.new(Specinfra::Command::Ubuntu::Base::Ppa)
Specinfra::Command::Linuxmint::Base::Service = Class.new(Specinfra::Command::Ubuntu::Base::Service)
```

Info from this [article](https://www.g-gent.com/nakanohito/growgent-advent-calendar-2015-10/)(in Japanese).

Or use the gem that I changed. I hope this pull request be accepted.

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'specinfra', github: 'ironsand/specinfra', branch: 'linuxmint_commands'
gem 'itamae'
```